# How to have regex to match middle of sentence?

Tags: c++, regex, c++14

I am trying to get a regex to match something on a string and then capture the rest of the string. According to https://regex101.com/ the regex below should work, but it is not. It seems like the c++ regex will match only from the start of the string. How can I get it to start from the middle of the string? I know that I can `.*?\/word(.*)` but I would rather not because the regex is a user input...

```
   std::string uri("a/word/");
   std::smatch match;
   std::regex rgx(R"(\/word(.*))");
   if (std::regex_match(uri, match, rgx)) {
      std::cout << match[0] << ' ' << match[1];
   }
```

Comment: You could try putting `.*` at the beginning of your pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) is supposed to match the entire input sequence, not some part of it. For the latter, you need [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

Using that, your example prints `/word/ /`.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/725f770f063e1d01)